# js math equation mystery

Tags: javascript, math

I'm new here :)

So, in javascript, I "simply" wanted to solve X in an equation:
My original formula was:

```
var X = (((((k/(cc**ci))-bk*)/(0.01*kg))-18)/((0.1+0.05*d1)*(280/(w+100)))-sd)
```

If I recall correctly, it returned some ridiculously high number...

Ok, I guess that was one problem... so, I tried this:

```
var X = (((((k*1.0/(cc*1.0*ci*1.0))-bk*1.0)/(0.01*kg*1.0))-18)/((0.1+0.05*d1*1.0)*(280/(w*1.0+100)))-sd*1.0)
```

Now it worked quite well for these simple variables:
cc=0, ci=0, bk=100, kg=100, d1=10, w=100, sd=10

BUT.. when the solution was approaching 0, it suddenly went completely crazy.
In this case, if k=126.4 the solution should be 0. However, I'm getting "7.1054273576" instead. I calculated it with different programs (even my old pocket-calculator lol), and they all say it's 0 --> so I guess my equation should be correct.

I tried k=126.5, which returns 0.119.
and k=126.3, which returns -0.119
These are correct.
So logically k=126.4 should return 0... but it doesn't. It still returns 7.1(...) instead.

I even tried replacing all the variables with the (see above) numbers:

```
var X = (((((126.4*1/(1*1*1*1))-100*1)/(0.01*100*1))-18)/((0.1+0.05*10*1)*(280/(100*1+100)))-10)
```

--> THIS STILL RETURNS TO 7.1(...), although it should be 0.
So the problem is definitely not one of my variables.
For these tests I was using an input type="number" object to review the results, if that is of any relevance...

I still can't see the problem, this seems absolutely illogical and is a complete mystery to me. Pls help!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `e-10` or something at the end? Something like `7.1054273576e-10`?

Comment: basic datatypes aren't exact when it comes to precision computations so as the other comment mentions, your number might look like '7.1054....' but in reality its actually just really close to 0. This could happen if there is a slight rounding issue at any one point in the equation... I'd recommend breaking it up to one operation per line so you can see exactly what the value is at each step

Answer (score 5):

You missed the bit at the end. `X` is equal to:

```
7.105427357601002e-15
                 ^
                 Scientific Notation!
```

Note the `e-15` at the end. That means, in decimal notation, it's

```
0.000000000000007105427357601002
```

Or in other words, very close to 0, as far as most uses are concerned. The difference between it and 0 likely comes about by rounding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed an e-15 at the end. So if anybody else is stumbling across this page they can stop wondering.

A very simple solution: Just use Math.round() in this case to reduce the number of integers behind the comma, so that "e" doesn't get used to describe the number.